# Passing parameter to other function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want pass variable of one function to the other how can i do that.Tried every trick googled every where but no result.

```
        public function blog() {

        $user_session_email = $this -> session -> userdata('user_email','name','id');
        if(!$user_session_email) {
            redirect('/');
        } 

        $user_data = $this -> users_model -> MyAccount([
            'id' => $this -> session -> userdata('id'),
            'name' => $this -> session -> userdata('name'),
            'email' => $this -> session -> userdata('user_email'),
        ]);
        $data["persoanl"] = $user_data;

        $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
        $messages["message"] = $returned_result['message'];

        $post_id = $this -> input -> post('post_id');
        $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
        $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/blog_form', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/footer');
    }
```

I want to pass **$post_id** to the below function

```
    public function load_messages() {
        $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
        $messages["message"] = $returned_result["message"];

        $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
        $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

        $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
    }
```

Comment: is this `public function load_messages() {` inside model??

Comment: it is both in model and in controller

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring the variable as a global?

```
        $post_id = null;
        public function blog() {
        global $post_id;
        $user_session_email = $this -> session -> userdata('user_email','name','id');

        if(!$user_session_email) {
            redirect('/');
        } 

        $user_data = $this -> users_model -> MyAccount([
            'id' => $this -> session -> userdata('id'),
            'name' => $this -> session -> userdata('name'),
            'email' => $this -> session -> userdata('user_email'),
        ]);
        $data["persoanl"] = $user_data;

        $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
        $messages["message"] = $returned_result['message'];

        $post_id = $this -> input -> post('post_id');
        $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
        $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/blog_form', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/footer');
    }

    public function load_messages() {
        global $post_id;
        $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
        $messages["message"] = $returned_result["message"];

        $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
        $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

        $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
public function blog() {

        $user_session_email = $this -> session -> userdata('user_email','name','id');
        if(!$user_session_email) {
            redirect('/');
        } 

        $user_data = $this -> users_model -> MyAccount([
            'id' => $this -> session -> userdata('id'),
            'name' => $this -> session -> userdata('name'),
            'email' => $this -> session -> userdata('user_email'),
        ]);
        $data["persoanl"] = $user_data;

        $post_id = $this -> input -> post('post_id');
        $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages($post_id);
        $messages["message"] = $returned_result['message'];

        $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
        $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/blog_form', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
        $this -> load -> view('users/inc/footer');
    }
```

Just make sure you get the post_id before you call the load_messages function.  Then when you call it, you pass $post_id in...

```
public function load_messages($post_id) {
     // Use $post_id as you wish...
     $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
     $messages["message"] = $returned_result["message"];

     $return_comments = $this -> users_model -> return_comments();
     $messages['comments'] = $return_comments;

     $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
}
```

Comment: no result still shows the empty while if i echo the $post_id in blog function it shows the id because the id is being posted there, not in the load_messages function

Comment: @WaleedIkhlaq, put an echo 'Post ID: '.$post_id after you set the variable in your blog() function, and make sure it's getting set.  If it is, remove that echo and place the same thing as line 1 of your load_messages() function.  Does it show up when you echo it from the load_messages function?

Comment: it shows on blog() function when echo but not on load_messages because  in ajax i have defined the blog() controller as a target so that's why blog() is getting value